# syntax to update all fields in a table in one statement in sql

Tags: sql, jdbc

Can anyone suggest a Syntax to update all fields in a table in one statement.
I want to use it with prepared statement in jdbc.
can anyone suggest a example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE your_table_name SET field1 = 'value1', field2 = 'value2'
```

**Note** : I haven't specified `WHERE` clause, so these changes will be applied to every single row in a table.

Comment: this could have been easily done even with the use of simple `Statement`.

Answer (score 2):

Using a prepared statement is not that complicated:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
      "UPDATE my_table SET column_1 = ?, column_2 = ?, column_3 = ?");
// assuming table has columns named as column_1,column_2,column_3 of type int,String,BigDecimal respectively

/* putting the values at runtime */
pstmt.setInt(1, 42); // use value 42 for column_1
pstmt.setString(2, "foo"); // use value 'foo' for column_2
pstmt.setBigDecimal(3, new BigDecimal("123.456")); // use 123.456 for column_3

pstmt.executeUpdate();
connection.commit();
```

Of course you will need to add error handling to this example.

More examples can be found in the Java Tutorial:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: in accordance with the question this ^ should have been accepted answer as it takes use of `PreparedStatement`